# Express dynamic route's get added to static routes middleware stack

Tags: node.js, express

I am defining static & dynamic routes in Express, and I have built a generic responder to send response to client. The responder is global to all routes and thus added at the end.

However, when I define static routes, matching dynamic routes' middlewares get added to the stack before the responder.

To illustrate:

```
server.get('/hello/test', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('/hello/test');
    next();
});
server.get('/hello/:page', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('/hello/:page');
    next();
});
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).send('test');
});
```

Calling `curl localhost:3000/hello/test` will console.log both '/hello/test' and '/hello/:page' before the responder middleware gets called. I only want the first matching routes middleware to be called.

Is there anyway to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: have you tried removing ´next();´ from the first route?
--> http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.METHOD

Comment: @John how would i reach the responder middleware without next()?

Answer (score 0):

The method next() is passing the control to the next handler.
You could solve your issue just removing the next() call from your routes, and putting the middleware into a function:

```
server.get('/hello/test', myMiddleware(req, res, next), function(req, res) {
    console.log('/hello/test');
});
server.get('/hello/test_b', myMiddleware(req, res, next), function(req, res) {
    console.log('/hello/test_b');
});
server.get('/hello/:page', myMiddleware(req, res, next), function(req, res) {
    console.log('/hello/:page');
});
server.get('*', myMiddleware(req, res, next), function (req, res) {
    res.type('txt').send('Not found');
});


function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    console.Log("in midleware")
    next();
}
```